# play: run console/ arbitary commands from a "stage-built" package

Tags: playframework

I have made an object and method `BackupRestore.backup( path)` that I can run from the dev console. I made a deployable package with the `stage` command. Now I cant freely open a console and call that method.

How can I run this method with a staged package?

I use play 2.1.1 and have installed it to server.

Comment: Why? What happens when you open a console?

Comment: "this is not a Play application" of course!

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error. I have created a new application, run stage, moved the folder to another place and then started the Play console. Did you mean dist instead of stage? Or did you only copy the `target` directory?

Comment: Yes, i copied only the target (and script) to another machine

Comment: As I understand, that's not the way to do it. Have a look [here at the section "Using the stage task"](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Production).